# Gatsby rebuild in production

Tags: gatsby, webhooks, strapi

I've been looking into the combination of Gatsby and Strapi and within the development enviroment it's quite easy to trigger a rebuild through the following command:
`"refresh": "curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/__refresh"`

However I've read that I need to rebuild gatsby in production if I want to display data changes, doing this through a webhook would be the way to go. But how do I go about such a thing. I can't seem to figure out how I can find or set up a webhook to trigger a rebuild of my gatsby frontend once a new entry gets added/updated in my Strapi backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A webhook is an action that runs when the application providing the webhook is notified. The webhook has a URL that can receive `HTTP` requests (usually `POST`). A request sent to this URL lets the application know that an event has happened and it may or may not contain a message.

Most CMS has its way of implementing webhooks but the configuration is usually based on a dashboard where the parameters are set. In your case, Strapi has a bunch of articles, videos and demonstrations about how to set webhooks.

Useful resources:

- https://strapi.io/blog/webhooks
- https://strapi.io/blog/what-is-a-webhook-and-how-does-it-work
- https://strapi.io/blog/strapi-webhooks
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5NQd8ruPl4&ab_channel=Strapi